# It took everything within me?

Tags: idioms, vocabulary

In a documentary I'm watching, a teenager is missing and her car is found. In the car's truck a bag can be seen, and they suspect that she might be inside of the bag. Her father states:

> It *took everything within me* not to walk over there and open the trunk."

I understand [took](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/take): to grasp or grip; to get possession of.

But what is "everything within me"?

What does he mean by that?

Comment: It means it was *all but impossible* for him to hold back from walking over and open the trunk. That he was required to exercise or expend *everything* which was in him -- all his strength and will -- to hang back and *not* open the trunk. In other words: he wanted *really badly* to go open that trunk. But he didn't. He resisted.

Comment: Thank you so much for the nicely put, well explained reply :)

Comment: [Merriam-Webster's 10.e(3) definition of *take (tr. v)*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/take): need, require < *it takes two to start a fight* >

Comment: I knew that meaning but that "within me" part confused me a little bit.

Comment: It means, more or less literally, "guts".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an idiom, with several different expressions:

- It took all I had...
- It took everything I had within me...
- I took all I had in me...

Etc.

It means one has to harness every bit of willpower one has in order to do (or not to do) something; one does it against their natural desire.

> I was so beaten down emotionally and *it took all I had within* me to finally decide to leave.
>   *It took all I had* to not burst out in laughter.
>   *It took all I had in me* to produce a smile and give her a limp handshake.
>   A pain so unbearable that *it took everything in me* to get up in the mornings.
>   *It took everything within me* to NOT loose my composure...

It can be used to express that it took *some* willpower (not to laugh) or *all* the willpower one has (to finally decide leave someone).

Another common way to say it is *It took every ounce of strength I had*:

> *It took every ounce of strength I had* to not turn and flee.

Answer (score 2):

It took everything within me - I used every bit of mental and physical strength in me to not move over to the said object.